# How to choose an image on device or access it's default gallery?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm making a mobile game for iOS/Android using Unity and for now I'm stuck in user avatar selection. For android I haven't found any methods to access it's default gallery folder. For iOS I've asked some developers and they say that system will not allow the application to leave it's folder and access any other. As I looked through some tutorials there are two ways of solving this:
1. Make an android activity and call it via `Intent`. Here I don't know how to solve it because I'm not an android developer.
2. Buy a plugin for 65$ (Etcetera).
Other methods are old or deprecated.
Has anyone met that trouble in Unity?

Comment: Either remove the iOS tag since you are not asking anything about iOS or  actually ask something - of course you can select an image from the gallery on iOS.

Comment: Actually it links with iOS. I wish I knew how exactly

Comment: There's no inbuilt way in Unity to access the gallery (or, for that matter, a ton of native features). You need to use a plugin to do so. Go to the asset store and see which one will fit your needs. There's a lot of native plugins, and some are even free.